Jupyterlab: How to change the spacing between cell-toolbar buttons
The Cell Toolbar settings allow you to add/remove items, being a "spacer" one of them. However it doesn't seem to have any effect.
Is there another way?

A very easy trick (much easier than inserting spacers here and there) is to add invisible characters to the "item label".
In this image you can see that there is an 'extra' separation before the last button. I don't want to click delete by mistake, so I got it farther from the previous button.

You can copy the invisible char from here
And then add as many as you want here (item label)
Jupyterlab > Settings > Settings Editor > Cell Toolbar

I have selected the invisible characters so you can see that they 'are' there (they occupy space, but cannot be seen).
If you add just normal spaces they are ignored.
